# What is completion of $\mathbf{Spec} \mathbb C[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology

I am a beginner of algebraic geometry. In some literature, I encounter a terminology: completion of $\mathbf{Spec} \mathbb C[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$.

> What is the precise meaning of this? Do you know any reference?

The terminology appears as follows. Let me denote the completion of $\mathbf{Spec} \mathbb C[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$ by $\mathbf P^1_\lambda$. Given a manifold $M$ (smooth, algebraic, or analytic), I want to study $\hat M:= M \times ( \mathbf P^1_\lambda \setminus\{0,\infty\} )$. And we put $\mathcal {\hat T} :=\mathrm{proj}_M^*(\mathcal T_M)$, where $\mathcal T_M$ is the tangent sheaf of $M$. Then any vector field $X$ of $M$ can be lifted in two ways: as a vector fields annihilating $\lambda$, or as a section of $\mathcal {\hat T}$.

> I know how to lift a vector field in the setting of differential geometry, but the lifting vector fields here involve a spectrum. So, how to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

I think "completion" here is meant in the sense of embedding the scheme in a complete projective variety.

To wit, $\mathbf{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, \infty\}$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$.

Since we are discussing a curve over an algebraically closed field, there's little harm in identifying $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ with the Riemann sphere — that is, the space of complex numbers together with the additional point $\infty$.

(and with the complex topology rather than the Zariski topology,  $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ really is homeomorphic to the sphere)

If we did so, $\lambda$ would then be the usual coordinate (more commonly called $z$), and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$ would consist of the complex numbers with the origin removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What should be the good of introducing $\mathbf {Spec} \mathbb C[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$ instead of $\mathbb C \setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: @Hang: Without knowing the context I can't really say what the source's purpose is. It could be anything from the author finding varieties the more natural language for discussion (e.g. the kind of person who would ask "What is the good of introducing $\mathbb{C} / \{ 0 \}$ instead of using $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$?") to wanting to emphasize that the object is amenable to study by the methods of algebraic geometry to introducing a toy example to demonstrate how to do algebraic geometry in a simple setting or any number of other things.